# Библиотека для обработки изображений

Tags: изображения, c++

Есть ли какая-либо библиотека на С++ для открытия jpeg, png, gif etc, парсинга их в массив пикселей и, желательно, свертки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV
Библиотек для открытия куча, а OpenCV - это мощный набор кучи функций для обработки ( распознование, бинаризация, свертка, фурье и т. д. )

Answer (score 2):

- [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)
- [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) - в принципе эквивалентный, это форк ImageMagick. В некоторых задачах сильно производительней.
- [GD Graphics Library](http://www.libgd.org/) - в php любят использовать.

Все эти либы под многие платформы и не только под с++. Первыми двумя пользовался, достаточно хорошо работают.

Answer (score 1):

Распространенный вариант. Правда это набор библиотек

1. [libJpeg](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg)
2. [libPng - Официальная эталонная библиотека, для работы с PNG](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libpng)
3. libTiff, libGif, libMng и т.д.
4. А также [FreeImage](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeImage) - свободная библиотека для поддержки графических форматов, таких как PNG, BMP, JPEG, TIFF и других. Использует libtiff, libjpeg, libpng, libmng и zlib.

OpenCV - мощнючая библиотека, но направлена на системы компьютерного зрения. Легко справится с большим кол-вом задач обработки информации. Но и изучать ее труднее.