# Побитовая обработка изображений

Tags: c

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, библиотеки, функции для побитовой обработки изображения в формате .jpeg средствами языка С. Интересует, каким именно образом можно побитово "прочитать" изображение для дальнейшей работы с ним.

Comment: Это какое-то учебное задание в свете неумолимо приближающейся сессии? Биты в JPEG - бессмыслица. Возможно, прогуляли лекцию на которой давали определение **пиксела**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подойдет [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/):

```
FIBITMAP *bitmap = FreeImage_Load(FIF_JPEG, filename, JPG_DEFAULT);
```

Дополнительно: [библиотека для обработки изображений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/41407/).

Comment: Подскажите, где можно прочитать об этой библиотеки, на русском языке. Что-то не нахожу соответствующей документации.

Comment: Попробуйте [Переводчик Google][1]


  [1]: http://translate.google.ru

Comment: На русском, к сожалению, нет. Можно через [переводчик](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/).

Comment: @niki-timofe и @byte И вспомнятся "гуртовщик мыши" и "гениталий на гусеничном ходу" (mouse driver и trackball).

Comment: Насколько я поняла, данная функция загружает в память графический файл для дальнейшей работы с ним. А вот как дальше прочитать, яркость и прочие параметры каждого бита, я не поняла.